# How to open particular page in a remote PDF?

Tags: android, pdf

I want to open particular page in pdf via web url. So I have to use below code but it's not working.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
            "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=www.yourpdf.com#page=8"
                .replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
        Log.e("intent", "" + browserIntent);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: does above code is open PDF?

Comment: yup, it's open pdf in an android web browser, but not open particular page.

Comment: Have you tried "?" Instead of "#"? That been asked, though, there is no real binding standard for such options, just a notion what Adobe browser plugins accept which is what other viewers more or less imitate.

Comment: Yes, I have used "?" also but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you directly hit your URL like below,

> https://chinesevoicebot.azurewebsites.net/HUAWEI%20Mate%209%20User%20Guide(MHA-L09_MHA-L29_01_English_Normal).pdf#page=100

It will redirect to your preferred page.

That means **docs.google.com**(embedded URL) is not allowing the parameter named page/pagenumber.

Comment: yes, It will redirect to a particular page but first android chrome browser download a pdf file and then redirect to a particular page.My concern is without download pdf file I want to redirect to particular page for this reason I have to use docs.google.com

Comment: Understood what you are trying to say. But I am telling that, docs.google.com might not allowing this kind of operations.

Comment: yes true... but any other way to achieve this kind of functionality in android.

Comment: No I haven't tried this library.Instead of third party library, is this possible in google doc?

Comment: I don't think so with Google Docs!